# How to implement Like button functionality with facebook's Unity3D plugin (7.4.0)

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I do not seem to find an explanation by facebook as to how (and if) to implement a "like the app" functionality within a Unity game using the facebook plugin for it.

Anyone has an idea whether this is possible with facebook 7.4.0 plugin for Unity?

Comment: I have a feeling it is not done within the app but most likely a link opening the page and up to the user to press it. I would think that if you could create a like process from the app, you could actually do it without any consent. So it would make sense you let it to the user. But I could be wrong.

Comment: FB unity sdk does not have like button for now. I ended up writing a plugin on native side. stupid.

Comment: I suspected that.

I'm Amazed how slow facebook is to address Unity plugin implementation and issues.

Comment: hi @gStation as a new user pls don't forget to Tick an answer

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen it appears that there is no direct "facebook like" button you can use for now.

It looks like you will have to simply make the in game button link to the games facebook page and allow the users to click like themselves.

Comment: Correct.  It is definitely the case there is no "inside-the-app" "direct" Like button for Facebook.  In fact, if your client wants a "FB - Like" button, it is nothing more than a link to open facebook, to the relevant product. like this: Application.OpenURL("http://www.facebook.com/15733311112222");